# D3 Tree View, is key "children" required to properly display a tree

Tags: json, treeview, d3.js

I have a JSON I'm getting from another source to display in D3 Tree View. The JSON is a tree structure but doesn't use the keyword "children" to define child nodes. I don't have any control over the incoming JSON and text denoting child nodes may change. Is D3 Tree View completely dependent upon the keyword "children" or does D3 have a way to use other strings to denote child nodes?

Below is a simplified version of the JSON I'm getting.

```
{
    "name": "some string",
    "score": "0.29",
    "weight": "0.8",
    "task1": [
        {
            "name": "some string",
            "score": "0.19",
            "weight ": "0.2",
            "subtask1": [
                {
                    "score": "0.11",
                    "weight ": "0.1",
                    "name": "some string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "task2": [
        {
            "name": "some string",
            "score": "0.19",
            "weight ": "0.2",
            "subtask1": [
                {
                    "score": "0.11",
                    "weight ": "0.1",
                    "name": "some string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the function to get the children of a node. See [the API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout#wiki-children).